# Finding common factors in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, factors

We need to find all common factors for a list of integers:

```
val b = List(4, 8, 12)
b: List[Int] = List(4, 8, 12)
```

Getting the minimum value in the list:

```
val min_b = b.min
min_b: Int = 4
```

Iterating through the range from 1 to min_b and checking if every element in b is divisible by the iterator's current value works, but the output contains empty `AnyVals`:

```
val factors_of_b = (1 to min_b)
  .map { x => if (b.forall{ z => z % x == 0 }) x }
```

Results in:

```
factors_of_b: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(1, 2, (), 4)
```

Yielding zeros in place of inapplicable factors and filtering the result for zeros is one workaround, but maybe there exists a cleaner, more Scala-esque solution?

```
val factors_of_b = (1 to min_b)
  .map { x => if(b.forall{ z => z % x == 0 }) x else 0 }
  .filterNot(_ == 0)
```

Results in:

```
factors_of_b: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 4)
```

Comment: To properly format larger pieces if code, indent by four spaces. Backpacks are for small single line pieces of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a `filter`:

```
scala> val b = List(4, 8, 12)
b: List[Int] = List(4, 8, 12)

scala> (1 to b.max).filter { x => b.forall{ z => z % x == 0 } }
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 4)
```

Also, I'm not sure why are you iterating until `b.max` instead of `b.min`, since the common factor won't be greater than any of the numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course it's b.min - my bad. Updated accordingly.